# Oracle database performance tuning

Tags: oracle11g

i)How to find out the long running query in oracle? 
ii)How to find out the long running error query?

Please help me on this.

Comment: What is "long running error query"?

Comment: Sometimes the query may produce results even if it runs long time. But some queries runs for long time without producing any results. Can you please help me on this. How to find out the queries.

Comment: How do you imagine it? Do you want to make a tool that will exam your database in real-time? What is a typical scenario for this need?

Comment: Lets say , we have a big package and it is running for long time and we are not aware where it get stuck? and which part of query is taking long time? . This is the question i faced in all the interviews. Can you please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to profile your stored procedures.

I used to use PL/SQL Developer for profiling my PL/SQL packages and procedures, it showed me all bottlenecks with detail information about time and resources. I believe all IDE for oracle have to have this functionality, you can choose your favorite one.

Answer (score 0):

Use the AWR report from enterprise manager if you are running it. If you don't have access to this then you can use EXPLAIN PLAN, TKPROF, or look at the dictionary tables like v$_session_longops.

e.g. http://blog.psftdba.com/2007/10/using-vsessionlongops-to-find-long.html